# best way to create perfect mirror of zfs based backup server

Tags: backup, freebsd, zfs

**The existing system:**
I have a FreeBSD based backup/archive server, which pulls the backups from the live servers via rsync every night and does a zfs snapshot to archive the backup contents for a specific time.

This results in the situation, that on this server there are lots of ...

- ... rsync tasks,
- ... storage pools (one for every backup task the server fullfills),
- ... snapshot tasks on that pools with different creation rules (from every 5 minutes to daily) and different retention times (from 3 days to 5 years),
- ... already existing snapshots (~8k).

**The task I want to accomplish now:**

I want to build a offsite server that is a perfect mirror of this backup server and which is syncing daily with the above described system.

**The Problem:**

I haven't found any solution yet, which lets me easily sync the whole server / zfs filesystem including all snapshots. I only know that you can send a single snapshot to a remote zfs filesystem via *zfs send*. Obviously it would be great to not have to recreate the complex pool & snapshot structure on the offsite server because I feel this would be a total mess maintenance wise.

Is there any solution which allows to mirror a complete zfs filesystem including snapshots?

Answer (score 2):

1. option - when you want to stay with FreeBSD, check FreeNAS to automate complexity you are afraid of.
2. option - NexentaStor, it is Solaris based storage appliance SW with great management web gui. Up to 18TB setup is for free. Again there you can easily manage complex `zfs send|receive` vs. a lot of datasets configuration.

If you have speedy lines between sites you want to mirror, I can imagine something like you export iSCSI volumes from sites storages and put them `zpool` mirror and add some local disks for ARC, ZIL, cache to lower read/write peaks running over iSCSI. If your storage is mainly for backups, then it would be OK. Nevertheless SUN once had such product behaving like that on ZFS.

Comment: Nobody uses Nexenta anymore!

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but could you elaborate a bit more how FreeNAS would help me with not having to configure everything twice? (BTW speed is not an issue at all, it's solely backup/archiving).

Comment: @ewwhite somebody do, otherwise they are already bankrupt... ;-) But yes, for me personally NexentaStore is no benefit. I assume the same for you.

Comment: @s1lv3r Check doc.freenas.org for docs how to setup periodic snapshots and their replication. There's push and pull option for replicating snapshots. This can save you time setting it up.

Comment: ZFS replication does not fail gracefully (i.e. if one fails the whole pipeline gets jammed).  I've had much better results with rsync and local snapshots.  I'll use ZFS replication over a LAN, but nothing slower.

Comment: @quadruplebucky https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchx/index.html

Comment: @nudzo if one of the rep snaps fails, the others won't proceed, and if you're looking for a "mirrored fs" (which the OP asked about and is not solvable within ZFS anyway) rsync comes much closer to success over WAN.